# Indentation APA6 Class for > 2nd paragraphs after title

Tags: indentation, apa6

I'm not able to indent the paragraphs in my apa6 class document. For my masterthesis the supervisor wants all the paragraphs indented but the first one after the title. So far,  I've tried the following commands but It hasn't worked out yet:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
\indent
```

My minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style= apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{/Applications/TeX/library}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}
\section{Section1}
Paragraph one (not indented)

Paragraph two (should be indented but isnt)

\end{document}
```

I'm glad for any advices on this :)
Cheers!

Comment: If you try your example with some more text, I think you will see that both paragraphs are indented.  What you want to do is to suppress the indentation before the first paragraph.  Leave a blank line after the `\section` command, and then start the first paragraph with `\noindent`.

Comment: Do you really want to have your entire document to be APA-style or just the bibliography? In the latter case you could use an APA-style bib setting with any LaTeX class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the `apa6` class is the exact opposite to what you mention: by default, the first line of *all* paragraphs, including the first line of the first paragraph after a sectional unit, are indented.

To suppress the indentation for the first line after a sectional unit of type `\section` and `\subsection`, you can redefine the values of some skips defined by the class (in my example, I suppreseed some packages that were not relevant to the issue discussed):

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\makeatletter
\b@level@one@skip=-2.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex
\b@level@two@skip=-2.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex
\makeatother

\setlength\parindent{1.27cm}

\newcommand\Text{Some test text for the example }

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\Text\Text\Text\Text\Text

\Text\Text\Text\Text\Text

\subsection{Test subsection}
\Text\Text\Text\Text\Text

\Text\Text\Text\Text\Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would suggest you to use, if possible (i.e., if your supervisor allows you), a different document class; personally, I don't like the settings offered by `apa6`.

Comment: Great. It worked! Thanks a lot.
However, now I have the problem, that when I want to flushleft the text (style rule for the thesis) the indentation disappears. I cant have both, right?
Which other class would you suggest using?

Comment: @teeglaze Since `\raggedright` sets `\parindent` to `0pt`, you need to set `\parindent` after `\raggedright`, using something like 
`\raggedright
\setlength\parindent{1.27cm}` in the preamble. Perhaps you could load the `ragged2e` package and use its `\RaggedRight` command instead of the standard `\raggedright`. As to which other class to use, it depends mainly on the specific requirements you need for your document. A number of questions in this site refer to writing thesis, so you could search and take a look; if no answer satisfies you, you can always start a new question.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! I am really glad that you - with your expertise - helped me out ;)